# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning when testing React component with Jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

So I want to test my `Login` component with Jest and React Testing Library.
Tests pass but I receive a:

> "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning".

How do I get rid of this message?

This is the function I mock in top of the test file:

```
jest.mock('../../../api/endpoints/auth/login/login', () => {
  return {
    login: jest.fn()
  };
});
```

And this is the function usage directly in test:

```
(login as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce(() => ({
  messages: ["Password is not correct"],
  isError: true
}));
act(() => {
  fireEvent.click(submitButton, leftClick);
});

await wait(() => {
  expect(getByTextLogin("Password is not correct")).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(window.location.href).toContain('/login');
});
```

Maybe I'm missing something when mocking an async function?

Comment: Please provide code as text, [not as links to pictures to text](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Answer (score 0):

Please put the code in the question, not pictures.

You're not handling the case of the promise rejecting when using async/await. Wrap your await in a try/catch.

Here's a link to jest's documentation highlighting this: [Jest Async](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async)

Comment: Sorry, i changed pictures to code blocks. What function from test should i wrap in try catch?